# Conflict between location and url_launcher plugin

Tags: ios, plugins, dart, flutter

I'm developing an app which finds points of interest around the location of the user. To get the location of the user I use the [location](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location) plugin which works quite nicely.
The next thing I'd like to implement is a button to open the default mapping application to navigate the user to the POI. I went at it using the [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) plugin and the geo: url scheme for android and the maps: scheme for iOS.
Independent of each other both plugins work as expected. Once I had both plugins in my project the problems started. Using the default setup of `flutter create` I get the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 6 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (`arm64`)

Finding Podfile changes
  - Flutter
  - location
  - url_launcher

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `/Users/rainerwittmann/Flutter/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `location` from `/Users/rainerwittmann/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-1.0.2/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `/Users/rainerwittmann/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-0.4.2+1/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  - Flutter
  - location
  - url_launcher

Downloading dependencies

-> Using Flutter (1.0.0)

-> Using location (0.0.1)

-> Using url_launcher (0.0.1)
  - Running pre install hooks
[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: location

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in verify_framework_usage'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:443:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:443:in `block in verify_framework_usage'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:440:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:440:in `verify_framework_usage'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:114:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 6.
```

So far so good. Adding use_frameworks! to my podfile, as suggested by the error message resulted in another error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 6 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** CLEAN FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Xcode's output:
↳
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = x86_64
    BUILD_DIR = /Users/rainerwittmann/Flutter/zapfsuche/build/ios
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.3

=== CLEAN TARGET location OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
“Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

=== CLEAN TARGET url_launcher OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET url_launcher OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

=== BUILD TARGET location OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
“Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 6.
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to proceed from here. Can somebody help me sort this out?

**Note**
This problem only exists on iOS. Both plugins work like a charm on android.

Answer (score 0):

Swift plugins require use_frameworks! and that isn't fully supported yet.

I'm [currently working](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10968) on it. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: So I can't use both plugins simultaneously? Is there a workaround?

Comment: There's a workaround discussed in the bug (the `pre_install` hook). If you copy the headers into place manually it works. I am working on doing this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Podfile

Add/uncomment after "target 'Runner' do" line number ~35

```
use_frameworks!
```

Then add this line after line number ~67

```
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
```

Example:

```
target 'Runner' do
  ** use_frameworks!  **
........ ......

post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
          ** config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0' **
        end
      end
    end
```

delete your Podfile.lock and try.